# Hotel details in Schengen visa form

Tags: visas, schengen, hotels

I am filling out a Schengen visa form for Iceland but as I will be travelling to multiple countries, I have booked multiple hotels.

The area in the form to fill out hotel details is quite small, so I am wondering which hotel details to add there. Will it be my first stay only or all hotels? Or will it be my first stay in Iceland, which is not my first destination?

Comment: I would list all hotels on a separate sheet, and put "See attachment #1" on the actual form.

Comment: @GeorgeY. : Thanks. Just wanted to check if you have tried this or have seen others trying this way.

Comment: I did this, although for a different visa.